# instantiate object in foreach

Tags: php

Is there a way to do this having to instantiate the object inside the loop itself?

```
foreach ($primaryKeys as new foo($primaryKey){
    // do stuff with the object we just instantiated
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just instantiate it inside the loop...

```
foreach ($primaryKeys as $primaryKey{
    $pk = new foo($primaryKey);
    // do stuff with the object we just instantiated
}
```

Is it not working that way?

Comment: It works just fine, see my question.. I know you can do it inside the loop, just wondering if there was a way to do it inside the foreach() itself to clean up the code a little.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as you cannot assign variables inside of `foreach` with `=`. And you cannot work with instance of object if you don't have it assigned anywhere.

However, this will do the trick:

```
foreach ($primaryKeys as $primaryKey) {
    $whatever[] = new foo($primaryKey);
}
```